How to change a price when I click in color?
I had a question, when we click on the colors on store sites, the seller of that product changes, the warranty of that product changes, and the price of that color of the product, how is the database analysis implemented?
What I did is the color_product table and I must have it.
There is also a prices table and I must have it because the price of the product can change at any time and I want to show the price list to the user on the site.
colors table
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('colors', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('color_name');
        $table->string('color_code');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

categories table
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('latin');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->string('awesome')->nullable();
        $table->integer('parent_id');
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

products table
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('brand_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->string('title');
        $table->string('slug');
        $table->string('latin');
        $table->string('latin_slug');
        $table->integer('product_number')->nullable();
        $table->integer('view')->default(0);
        $table->integer('order_product')->default(0);
        $table->boolean('status');
        $table->boolean('publish');
        $table->text('introduction');
        $table->longText('expert_check');
        $table->text('keywords')->nullable();;
        $table->text('descriptions')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

warranties table
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('warranties', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('color_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('date');
        $table->string('time');
        $table->string('price');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

prices table
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('prices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->string('value'); //price in here
        $table->boolean('is_active')->default(0);
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

category_product
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('category_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('category_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->primary(['category_id' , 'product_id']);
    });
}

color_product
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('color_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->foreignId('color_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('product_id')->constrained()->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->primary(['color_id' , 'product_id']);
    });
}


you need to add the table for the store_inventory which contains the store_id,product_id,attribute_id (variant means size,color,weight), attribute_value_id (values like red,black,55 MM, 10KG)
Note : add the tables for the attributes and attributes_values
